# recurrence relation using master method

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I know that the Master theorem is used for the recurrence relations of the form:
$$T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$$
In my question, I am supposed to solve the following recurrence relation by using Master theorem:
$$T(n)=T(n/4)+n^{1/2}+5$$
$$T(1)=3$$
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think $f(n)$, $a$ and $b$ are in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice way to deal with such a recurrence is to define a new sequence $U_k$:

$$T\left(4^k\right) = U_k$$

that satisfies

$$U_k - U_{k-1} = 2^k + 5$$

$$U_0=3$$

This is a linear, inhomogeneous recurrence relation with general solution

$$U_k = A \cdot 2^k + B k +C$$

Plugging back into the equation and applying the initial condition, we find that

$$U_k = 2^{k+1} + 5 k + 1$$

which means that, using $T(n) = U_{(\log_2{n})/2}$

$$T(n) = 2 \sqrt{n} + \frac{5}{2} \log_2{n} + 1$$

Comment: He references specifically the "Master Theorem" which is a general technique where he can just plug in values.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Hmmm.  Probably some confusion on part of the OP, where he states "solve," but is likely just interested in the dominant behavior of the solution as $n \to \infty$, as is the case when comp sci folks run across equations like this.  Meanwhile, it is eminently soluble, so he can see that the solution is $\Theta\left(n^{1/2}\right)$, which I guess follows from Case 3 in the Wikipedia article.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: Yeah, if you don't know the Master Theorem, the context would definitely be unclear.